# Does setup.py includes the packages installed with "pip install" in the same virtual env?

Tags: python

These are the steps I did, how I build my package from virtual env.

```
cd /data
python -m venv python_environment
source /data/python_environment/bin/activate
cd /data/python_environment/workspace
pip install sample1001
mkdir package_project
```

`package_project` folder contains `setup.py` file and subfolder `my_package` with `init.py` and `hello_world.py` script

```
cd package_project
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Setup.py contains:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
    setup(
        name = "my-package",
        version = "1.0.0",
        packages=['my-package']
    )
```

As output I do get wheel package in `/data/python_environment/workspace/package-project/dist/*.whl`

But this package does NOT include additional packages which I installed with `pip install`.
Shouldn't it?

In which way I ensure that once I deploy my package somewhere it does not have to install dependencies as well?
I read some articles but I am still not sure if my wheel package should contain or not additional packages which I install with `pip.install`

I also tried with `install_requires` option in `setup.py` like this
`install_requires=['sample1001'],`
but again my wheel package does not contain those additional packages (sample1001).

Did I mixed something?
What is the goal where `pip install` packages should persist when doing the `setup.py`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you've specified in `setup.py` should not include the dependencies. Why would it? Imagine you have hundreds of them, and you "pack(age)" everything together, your own python package plus the dependencies - the size of your package would be significant. What if those dependencies have their own dependencies? It grows really fast.

Now, you would like to specify that your package has some dependencies - that's what `install_requires` is for. When you run `pip install my_package` the `install_requires` directive will let pip know that your package uses other deps, and pip will install it for you automatically, you don't need to run `pip install` for each one of them.

You can test this by adding some dependencies (ones existing on pypi!) in `install_requires`, creating a **new virtualenv** and running from the folder your `setup.py` is in:

```
pip install . 
pip freeze
```

you should get your package and all it's dependencies listed on pip freeze - ready to run in your local environment.

Comment: Thank you for this kind and detailed explanation...so basically I even do not have a need to run any `pip install` actions on the environment where I just want to package my project - correct? Or I am wrong? I am doing the jenkins builds so I just need to make a package of a code downloaded from git... to me it does not seems as a required thing to really run `pip install` of y requirements on the same server, if I just want to create a package which will contain a list of dependencies in `install_requires` segment. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: It depends really what is your package supposed to do on the jenkins build. In cases which I know from my experience, you usually do a CI to test your package, in this case yes - you need to also install it on jenkins (using pip install), otherwise the jenkins python environment does not know anything about the existence of your package in "runable" sense - it is simply just a code, not loaded to the python environment.

Comment: yes. agree... if the package needs to be run against some tests - then I will first do the build of the package, put requirements in the `setup.py` file, install it with e.g. `pip install my_package-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl` and then run tests...
But if I need just to make a `whl` package then I do not need to execute any pip install of the requirements for that `whl` package, correct? Thanks a lot

Comment: if you need to test the package - I assume you will write and control it's code - you don't need to build any whl for it. You just pull the code from git directly to your jenkins build ( as in `git clone my_repo`) then `cd my_repo` and `pip install .` it will work the same as in your local computer. I am not sure I see any need to build .whl for running tests in jenkins, but maybe I am missing context on this one

Comment: kpsherva could you please help me with the following question? Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867807/python-wheel-packages-how-to-add-timestamp-to-the-wheel-name

Answer (score 1):

In Short: No, compiling a package into a wheel file will not package up the dependencies with it. Listing those packages simply tells the installer to go out and get those dependencies.

You don't need to go into an environment after activating it. I think you may have a misunderstanding in the difference between a package and a virtual env.

The purpose of a virtual environment is to provide an isolated environment with only the dependencies/packages you need. A setup.py file is used to create and install a package in an environment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this kind and detailed explanation...so basically I even do not have a need to run any `pip install` actions on the environment where I just want to package my project - correct? Or I am wrong? I am doing the jenkins builds so I just need to make a package of a code downloaded from git... to me it does not seems as a required thing to really run `pip install` of y requirements on the same server, if I just want to create a package which will contain a list of dependencies in `install_requires` segment. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: m25  could you please help me with the following question? Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867807/python-wheel-packages-how-to-add-timestamp-to-the-wheel-name