# Python wheel packages - how to add timestamp to the wheel name?

Tags: python, python-wheel

I am using Jenkins to create a new build packages for Python.
My `setup.py` file is the following:

```
setup(
    name = "my-package",
    version = "1.0.0",
    author = "Bob Bob",
    description = "test",
    packages=['my-package'],
    install_requires=['sample1001']
)
```

We run:
`python setup.py bdist_wheel`
The resulting file is the following:
`my_package-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`

I know that by simple `version` change I can impact my wheel package name. But most of the time if some small change is being set we do not want to change the `version` field, but we would like to add `timestamp` to the existing name of the wheel package, so that we can have different build file (not to overwrite the previous one),

Can you please tell me - how I can add timestamp to wheel name? I cannot find that info anywhere...

Thanks a lot!

***UPDATE:***
I tried solution suggested by Keith:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from os.path import dirname,abspath
with open('Bundle/requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'Readme.Md')).read()

setup(
    name='fa-bundle',
    version='1.0.0',
    install_requires=requirements,
    description='Bundle is a project that will replace old Package Manager',
    long_description=read('Readme.Md'),
    use_scm_version=True,
    setup_requires=['setuptools_scm'],
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author='FCS',
    python_requires=">=3.9, <4",
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/fa-bundle/base/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py",
line 87, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py",
line 139, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py",
line 476, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py",
line 275, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py",
line 900, in finalize_options
    ep(self)
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py",
line 920, in _finalize_setup_keywords
    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/fa-bundle/base/.eggs/setuptools_scm-7.0.4-py3.9.egg/setuptools_scm/integration.py",
line 90, in version_keyword
    _assign_version(dist, config)
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/fa-bundle/base/.eggs/setuptools_scm-7.0.4-py3.9.egg/setuptools_scm/integration.py",
line 62, in _assign_version
    _version_missing(config)
  File "/data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/fa-bundle/base/.eggs/setuptools_scm-7.0.4-py3.9.egg/setuptools_scm/__init__.py",
line 109, in _version_missing
    raise LookupError( LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for /data/jenkins/pypi/fabundle/fa-bundle/base.

Make sure you're either building from a fully intact git repository or
PyPI tarballs. Most other sources (such as GitHub's tarballs, a git
checkout without the .git folder) don't contain the necessary metadata
and will not work.

For example, if you're using pip, instead of
https://github.com/user/proj/archive/master.zip use
git+https://github.com/user/proj.git#egg=proj
```

Comment: In the future, please format terminal output like code, not as a block quotation.

Comment: I managed to do this with my custom function `get_version` to add timestamp and to read version number from some custom file: `version=get_version()`

Answer (score 1):

If you put your project under `git` SCM, and then use [setuptools_scm](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm) it will manage the version for you from git tags. that includes marking it "dirty" when building. The built version is automatically adjusted.

Comment: Hi Keith could you please provide clarification on this? Yes we are using git and downloading our code from there and then running the build. Now I do not know what you wanted to say with: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm
you wanted to say I should not use setup.py? Could you please provide some examples or similar... Why would I have to use git tags?? I do not see that as something we are required to do.
Can I do simple rename of the wheel package afterwards at the end once it is already built or that is not recommendable? Thank you

Comment: It's not recommended, since the version has a defined format. The setuptools_scm works with the setup.py. Just read their docs.

Comment: they are mentioning `setup_requires`  but aren't they really talking about `install_requires`? I am confused with this argument. I suppose you wanted me to read the chapter `setup.py usage (deprecated)` from the docs, correct?

Comment: yes. They do mean "setup_requires".  The deprecation is related to the use of setup.py itself. It will still be used for a long time to come, so don't worry about that now. But if you want, use the pyproject.toml style.

Comment: Thanks but I am facing some issue when adding the `setup_requires`. Could you please take a look? I have provided updated code and output. Thanks!

Comment: That's an entirely different problem. Your setup specifies python >= 3.9, but you're running that with Python 3.6. Python 3.6 doesn't have the "annotations" future import and fails. If you really want 3.6 you might have to use an older version of setuptools_scm.

Comment: Thank Keith. I will upgrade it to 3.9 and let you know

Comment: can you please take a look once again?
I have folder `fa-bundle`. Within it I have a .`git` subfolder and `base` subfolder. Within the `base` I have `setup.py` and `Bundle` subfolder with all python scripts and `__init.py__` needed for detecting the packages. I am of course running the python script `setup.py` from its folder.

Comment: Keith can you please assist me on this?  I am really struggling to understand why is this versioning so hard - this is just a very regular thing to have somehow automically during the build new version of the file marked with different name (developer is just modifying the code they should not worry about `version` field which needs to updated in that case). Can you please tell me how this process usually works? I can't understand why this is so complicated to mark new package build with time when this was generated...

Comment: I corrected the file!!! I have new output `fa_bundle-0.1.dev7+ga0415ea.d20220706-py3-none-any.whl` so it added this part - `0.1.dev7+ga0415ea.d20220706` how, why? what does it represent? I do not have any git tags and I do not think we need us git tags for our project. So how this formatted my wheel package like this? Based on what?

Comment: I do not see this as the best approach because in this way we are loosing basic info about the version... but please tell me what is the best practice... there must be some kind of recommendation for this... I think this is common for all who are building python packages, to track in the best possible way info about the version.. Thanks

Comment: The version name follows the [PEP-440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/) Python standard. There are multiple ways of setting the base version. I happen to like the setuptools_scm and using git tags. That's why I recommended it. I don't see a problem using git tags, as they have other useful purposes as well. There are other tools, or write your own version to a file and read that in inside the setup.py script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246214/discussion-between-keith-and-andreys).

Answer (score -1):

I would rather try to set Jenkins correctly if you want to preserve the previous builds rather than trying to force it by python package versioning, which is not meant for this usage.